# Make list of sentences in table break normally

Tags: tables, formatting

My table is a mess!

I have three columns (from left to right):

1. Left: very simple, single words.
2. Middle: a list of five options (there won't be more than five).
3. Left: a list of events taking place. These are long sentences and I inserted manual breaks to keep everything within the table boundaries. To make it easier to read, I also insert 9mm indents. It works ... okay. But I feel there must be a better, more elegant solution out there

Note: the list of words in the middle column is not linked to the list of events in the right column.

Any suggestions on how to insert these long sentences in the right column without having to add manual breaks?

Thanks.

Here's the code:

```
% PREAMBLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,centered,twocolumn]{book}
\special{papersize=210mm,297mm}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3.2cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft} % Customization of TOC LOF LOT
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} % For shading in tables
\usepackage{pdfcolmk}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{nicefrac} % To write fractions
\usepackage{attrib} % For source of quotations
\usepackage{lettrine} % For NewThought formatting
\usepackage{array} % To define width of columns in long table
\usepackage{booktabs} % Nicer spacing in columns
\usepackage{siunitx} % To write Celsius, etc.
\usepackage{enumitem} % To create item lists
\usepackage{caption} % To change way captions are labelled
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{threeparttable} % For table notes + To allow footnote material to stay with the tabular environment
\usepackage{etoolbox} % To make table footnote font smaller
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}
\usepackage{textcomp} % For Numero symbol
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec,color}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[linguistics,edges]{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newpxtext} % Font for document instead of obsolete Palatino


% To make TOC in two columns and List of Tables into one column.
\usepackage{multitoc}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@starttoc}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{toc}}{%
        \ifnum\multicolumntoc>1
        \begin{multicols}{\multicolumntoc}%
            \@multitoc@starttoc{#1}%
        \end{multicols}%
        \else
        \@multitoc@starttoc{#1}%
        \fi}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{lot}}{%
        \ifnum\multicolumnlot>1
        \begin{multicols}{\multicolumnlot}%
            \@multitoc@starttoc{#1}%
        \end{multicols}%
        \else
        \@multitoc@starttoc{#1}%
        \fi}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{lof}}{%
        \ifnum\multicolumnlof>1
        \begin{multicols}{\multicolumnlof}%
            \@multitoc@starttoc{#1}%
        \end{multicols}%
        \else
        \@multitoc@starttoc{#1}%
        \fi}{}%
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\multicolumnlot}{1}

% Change footnotes from numbers to symbols
\makeatletter
\def\@xfootnote[#1]{%
    \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{#1}%
    \@footnotemark\@footnotetext}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
    \small{
        \center
        \caption{Significant feasts and ceremonies of the five intercalary days.}\label{FeastsIntercalary}
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \begin{tabular}{cll}
                \toprule
                Intercalary Day & Names in the five languages & Celebrating group; location; celebration name; notes \\
                \midrule
                First & French: Bonjour\tnote{*} & Line One; Flower; Entering in the river; rituals and feasts. \\
                & German: Hallo & Line Two; Hand; Entering in the river; rituals and feasts \\
                & English: Hello & \hspace{9mm}lovely breakfast here!; Feasts and foods. \\
                & Spanish: Hola & Line Three; Hand; Entering in the river; rituals and feasts \\
                & Portugese: Ola & Line Four ; Hand; Entering in the river; rituals and feasts \\
                && \hspace{9mm}lovely breakfast here!; Feasts and foods. \\
                && Line Five; Hand; Entering in the river; rituals and feasts \\
                && \hspace{9mm}lovely breakfast here!; Feasts and foods. \\
                && Line Six; Hand; Entering in the river; rituals and feasts \\
                && \hspace{9mm}lovely breakfast here!; Feasts and foods. And the sentence \\
                && \hspace{9mm}continues, so I'm going to add another manual break, here!\\
                && Line Seven; Hand; Entering in the river; rituals and feasts \\
                && \hspace{9mm}lovely breakfast here!; Feasts and foods. \\
                && \\
                First & French: Bonjour\tnote{*} & Line One; Flower; Entering in the river; rituals and feasts. \\
                & German: Hallo & Line Two; Hand; Entering in the river; rituals and feasts \\
                & English: Hello & \hspace{9mm}lovely breakfast here!; Feasts and foods. \\
                & Spanish: Hola & Line Three; Hand; Entering in the river; rituals and feasts \\
                & Portugese: Ola & Line Four ; Hand; Entering in the river; rituals and feasts \\
                && \hspace{9mm}lovely breakfast here!; Feasts and foods. \\
                && Line Five; Hand; Entering in the river; rituals and feasts \\
                && \hspace{9mm}lovely breakfast here!; Feasts and foods. \\
                && Line Six; Hand; Entering in the river; rituals and feasts \\
                && \hspace{9mm}lovely breakfast here!; Feasts and foods. And the sentence \\
                && \hspace{9mm}continues, so I'm going to add another manual break, here!\\
                && Line Seven; Hand; Entering in the river; rituals and feasts \\
                && \hspace{9mm}lovely breakfast here!; Feasts and foods. \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tablenotes}
                \item[*] \blindtext.
            \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
    }
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for all the code, but I wanna make sure that whatever better solution comes up (if there's one) doesn't break what i already have!

Comment: I suggest using the `X` column type, hence a `tabularx` environment, and in this last column use a customised `description` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions using `tabularx` and `hanging`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,centered,twocolumn]{book}
\special{papersize=210mm,297mm}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3.2cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{clX}
First & \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{:~}l}
        French & Bonjour\\
        German & Hallo\\
        French & Bonjour\\
        German & Hallo\\
        French & Bonjour\\
        \end{tabular} &
   \begin{hangparas}{9mm}{1}

 \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}  
 Line Six; Hand; Entering in the river; rituals and feasts lovely breakfast here!; Feasts and foods. And the sentence continues, so I'm going to add another manual break, here! 

 Line Six; Hand; Entering in the river; rituals and feasts lovely breakfast here!; Feasts and foods. And the sentence continues, so I'm going to add another manual break, here! 

  Line Six; Hand; Entering in the river; rituals and feasts lovely breakfast here!; Feasts and foods. And the sentence continues, so I'm going to add another manual break, here! 
\end{hangparas}\\
First & \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
        French: Bonjour\\
        German: Hallo\\
        French: Bonjour\\
        German: Hallo\\
        French: Bonjour\\
        \end{tabular} &
   \begin{hangparas}{9mm}{1}

 \vspace{-\baselineskip}  
 Line Six; Hand; Entering in the river; rituals and feasts lovely breakfast here!; Feasts and foods. And the sentence continues, so I'm going to add another manual break, here! 

 Line Six; Hand; Entering in the river; rituals and feasts lovely breakfast here!; Feasts and foods. And the sentence continues, so I'm going to add another manual break, here! 

  Line Six; Hand; Entering in the river; rituals and feasts lovely breakfast here!; Feasts and foods. And the sentence continues, so I'm going to add another manual break, here! 
\end{hangparas}\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}



\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you. It works on its own, but once I include it in my book (after adding the "hanging" and "tabularx" packages, i get an "latex package longtable error not in 1-column mode" error message. Any suggestions?

Comment: @nofare: The error message you observe is due to the `ltablex` package that combines the features of `tabularx` and `longtable` (changes are applied to all `tabularx` environments). As `longtables` are not allowed in `twocolumn` mode that you explicitly use (see documentclass option) this results in the described error message. To overcome this, you could use `\onecolumn` right before `\begin{table*}` and `\twocolumn` right after `\end{table*}`. However, this will cause page breaks before and after the table.

Comment: If you want to prevent this and still want to use a package that combines `tabularx` and `longtable` features, you might want to switch to `xltabular` that keeps the original `tabularx` environment as it is.

Comment: I'm using the package ltablex. Would that work instead of switching to xltabular, which truth be told would be complicated?

Comment: As already stated in [my previous comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483108/make-list-of-sentences-in-table-break-normally/483139?noredirect=1#comment1222010_483139), you could use `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` but this will cause pagebreaks.

Comment: Correct. Just used that technique and it works. It's also something I use in other parts of the book, and so far so good. I can live with the page breaks. Thank you.