# Longtable word alignment issues

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, longtable

Some problems with my table.

I managed to poach ideas from this entry: [Make list of sentences in table break normally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483108/make-list-of-sentences-in-table-break-normally) and created this longtable (without using tabularx).
It works ... okay-ish.

Here are issues I was hoping to get some help with:

- The month numbers in the first column are aligned right. I'd like
  them centered.
- The words in "Column Two" are not properly aligned.
- On the second sceen capture, there is a huge gap between the
  sentences in the fourth column. That's because the first sentence ("I
  told him, etc.") is quite short. Of course, I could fix it manually, but would there be a way to make this adjustment more automatic?

Thank you.

```
% PREAMBLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[oneside,centered,twocolumn]{book}
%\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,centered,twocolumn]{book}
\special{papersize=215.9mm,279.4mm}
%\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3.2cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft} % Customization of TOC LOF LOT
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} % For shading in tables
\usepackage{pdfcolmk}
\usepackage{multirow}

%\usepackage{lscape} %to put the long table of dwellings sideways
%\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{nicefrac} % to write fractions
\usepackage{attrib} % For source of quotations
\usepackage{lettrine} % For NewThought formatting
\usepackage{array} % To define width of columns in long table
\usepackage{booktabs} % Nicer spacing in columns
\usepackage{siunitx} % To write Celsius, etc.
\usepackage{enumitem} % To create item lists
\usepackage{caption} % To change way captions are labelled
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{threeparttable} % For table notes + To allow footnote material to stay with the tabular environment
\usepackage{etoolbox} % To make table footnote font smaller
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}
\usepackage{textcomp} % For Numero symbol
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec,color}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[linguistics,edges]{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newpxtext} % Font for document instead of obsolete Palatino

\usepackage{hyperref} % Hyperlinks

\begin{document}

{\small
    \onecolumn\begin{longtable}
        {
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.2cm}
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4.5cm}
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{7.15cm}
        }

        \caption{This is a test.}\label{test} \\
        \toprule
        Month number & Months in the languages of the Five Empires & Date of the month & Deity or group celebrating the event, location, name of the
        celebration, and notes \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead

        \caption*{\autoref{test} (\textit{Continued})} \\
        \toprule
        Month & Months in the languages of the Five Empires & Date & Events \\
        \midrule    
        \endhead

        1 &\begin{tabular}[t]{l}
            French: Bonjour\\
            German: Hallo\\
            French: Bonjour\\
            German: Hallo\\
            \end{tabular}
        & 1st & Call me Ishmael. Some years ago—never mind how long precisely—having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. \\
        & \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
            French: Bonjour\
            \end{tabular}
        & '' & What of it, if some old hunks of a sea-captain orders me to get a broom and sweep down the decks? \\
        && '' & Call me Ishmael. Some years ago—never mind how long precisely—having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. \\
        && '' & What of it, if some old hunks of a sea-captain orders me to get a broom and sweep down the decks? \\
        && '' & Call me Ishmael. Some years ago—never mind how long precisely—having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. \\
        && 15th-16th & What of it, if some old hunks of a sea-captain orders me to get a broom and sweep down the decks? \\
        && 23rd & But no more of this blubbering now, we are going a-whaling, and there is plenty of that yet to come. Let us scrape the ice from our frosted feet, and see what sort of a place this Spouter may be. \\

        2 &\begin{tabular}[t]{l}
            French: Bonjour\\
            German: Hallo\\
            French: Bonjour\\
            German: Hallo\\
            German: Hallo\\
        \end{tabular} & 2nd & Call me Ishmael. Some years ago—never mind how long precisely—having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. \\
        && '' & Call me Ishmael. Some years ago—never mind how long precisely—having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. \\
        && '' & What of it, if some old hunks of a sea-captain orders me to get a broom and sweep down the decks? \\
        && '' & Call me Ishmael. Some years ago—never mind how long precisely—having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. \\
        && 23rd & What of it, if some old hunks of a sea-captain orders me to get a broom and sweep down the decks? \\
        && 28th & But no more of this blubbering now, we are going a-whaling, and there is plenty of that yet to come. Let us scrape the ice from our frosted feet, and see what sort of a place this Spouter may be. \\

        3 &\begin{tabular}[t]{l}
            French: Bonjour\\
            German: Hallo\\
            French: Bonjour\\
            German: Hallo\\
            German: Hallo\\
        \end{tabular} & 4th & I told him that I never liked to sleep two in a bed; \\
        && '' & Call me Ishmael. Some years ago—never mind how long precisely—having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. \\
        && '' & What of it, if some old hunks of a sea-captain orders me to get a broom and sweep down the decks? \\
        && '' & Call me Ishmael. Some years ago—never mind how long precisely—having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. \\
        && 7th & What of it, if some old hunks of a sea-captain orders me to get a broom and sweep down the decks? \\
        && 31st & But no more of this blubbering now, we are going a-whaling, and there is plenty of that yet to come. Let us scrape the ice from our frosted feet, and see what sort of a place this Spouter may be. \\
        \bottomrule

        %   \insertTableNotes

    \end{longtable}\twocolumn
}
%\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: If the header of the first olumn should also be centered, use `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.2cm}` instead of  `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.2cm}`

Comment: Perhaps you may use a `\multirow`commancd to have the fore lines span two or three rows.

Comment: you have loaded `fontspec` so must be using luatex or xetex, in which case do not load 8bit fonts with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and  `\usepackage{newpxtext}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following MWE, I have replaced `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.2cm}` by `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.2cm}` inorder to solve the first issue. In order to remove the second and third issue, I have used `\multirow`.

```
\documentclass[oneside,twocolumn]{book}

\special{papersize=215.9mm,279.4mm}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3.2cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

{\small
    \onecolumn\begin{longtable}
        {
            >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.2cm}
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4.5cm}
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{7.1cm}
        }

        \caption{This is a test.}\label{test} \\
        \toprule
        Month number & Months in the languages of the Five Empires & Date of the month & Deity or group celebrating the event, location, name of the
        celebration, and notes \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead

        \caption*{\autoref{test} (\textit{Continued})} \\
        \toprule
        Month & Months in the languages of the Five Empires & Date & Events \\
        \midrule    
        \endhead

        1 &\multirow{5}{=}{%
            French: Bonjour\\
            German: Hallo\\
            French: Bonjour\\
            German: Hallo\\
            French: Bonjour
            }
        & 1st & Call me Ishmael. Some years ago—never mind how long precisely—having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. \\
        & & '' & What of it, if some old hunks of a sea-captain orders me to get a broom and sweep down the decks? \\
        && '' & Call me Ishmael. Some years ago—never mind how long precisely—having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. \\
        && '' & What of it, if some old hunks of a sea-captain orders me to get a broom and sweep down the decks? \\
        && '' & Call me Ishmael. Some years ago—never mind how long precisely—having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. \\
        && 15th-16th & What of it, if some old hunks of a sea-captain orders me to get a broom and sweep down the decks? \\
        && 23rd & But no more of this blubbering now, we are going a-whaling, and there is plenty of that yet to come. Let us scrape the ice from our frosted feet, and see what sort of a place this Spouter may be. \\

        2 &\multirow{5}{=}{%
            French: Bonjour\\
            German: Hallo\\
            French: Bonjour\\
            German: Hallo\\
            German: Hallo\\
        } & 2nd & Call me Ishmael. Some years ago—never mind how long precisely—having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. \\
        && '' & Call me Ishmael. Some years ago—never mind how long precisely—having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. \\
        && '' & What of it, if some old hunks of a sea-captain orders me to get a broom and sweep down the decks? \\
        && '' & Call me Ishmael. Some years ago—never mind how long precisely—having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. \\
        && 23rd & What of it, if some old hunks of a sea-captain orders me to get a broom and sweep down the decks? \\
        && 28th & But no more of this blubbering now, we are going a-whaling, and there is plenty of that yet to come. Let us scrape the ice from our frosted feet, and see what sort of a place this Spouter may be. \\

        3 &\multirow{5}{=}{%
            French: Bonjour\\
            German: Hallo\\
            French: Bonjour\\
            German: Hallo\\
            German: Hallo\\
        } & 4th & I told him that I never liked to sleep two in a bed; \\
        && '' & Call me Ishmael. Some years ago—never mind how long precisely—having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. \\
        && '' & What of it, if some old hunks of a sea-captain orders me to get a broom and sweep down the decks? \\
        && '' & Call me Ishmael. Some years ago—never mind how long precisely—having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. \\
        && 7th & What of it, if some old hunks of a sea-captain orders me to get a broom and sweep down the decks? \\
        && 31st & But no more of this blubbering now, we are going a-whaling, and there is plenty of that yet to come. Let us scrape the ice from our frosted feet, and see what sort of a place this Spouter may be. \\
        \bottomrule


    \end{longtable}\twocolumn
}


\end{document}
```

Comment: That works beautifully. The multirow x 5 thing works super well. Thank you.